# Collecting Cron Tab entries across servers/users

Tags: bash, cron, aix

Struggling with this for a couple of days. Trying to create a space delimited list of $host $useraccount $crontab entries.

I've tried a couple of different ways. Each ending in a different level of disaster, The closest I've come is this, someone point out the obvious thing I'm missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#Global Crontab Inventory for Scripts
#
outputfile="/localpath/cronoutput.txt"
LPARLIST=/pathto/LPAR.txt

while read LPAR; 
do
    ping -c 1 $LPAR > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        for user in $(ssh -n $LPAR /opt/freeware/bin/ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs);
        do
            while read line;
            do
                echo "$LPAR $user $line"
            done <"$(ssh -n "$LPAR" /opt/freeware/bin/tail -n +29 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$user)"
        done
    fi
done <$LPARLIST
```

It seems to be complaining about trying to execute the output of the tail as a command.

./crons.sh: line 11: (Several pages of cropped cron entries): File name too long

./crons.sh: line 11: : No such file or directory

./crons.sh: line 11: #

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Global Crontab Inventory for Scripts
#
outputfile="/localpath/cronoutput.txt"
LPARLIST=LPAR.txt

cat $LPARLIST |
while read LPAR; 
do
    ping -c 1 $LPAR > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    for user in $(ssh -n root@$LPAR ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs);
    do
        ssh -n "root@$LPAR" tail -n +29 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$user |
        while read line;
        do
            echo "$LPAR $user $line"
        done
    done
    fi
done
```

I prefer `cat xxx | while ...` instead of redirecting input as you did.  In theory it should be the same.  I did not spot anything specifically wrong and I did not really change anything -- just rearranged what you had.

The advantage of the `cat xxx | while ...` technique is you can insert commands between the cat and the while.  In this case, I would not do the tail -n +29 because you are guessing the first 29 lines are junk but that might not be true.  Rather I would just do a cat of the file and then egrep out the lines that start with a hash `#`.  Again, .... yes, the cat is redundant but who really cares.  It is more general and easier to add and delete things.

I don't have the `/opt` packages installed and I would not depend upon them unless absolutely necessary.  You are increasing dependencies.  So I just used the local "ls" and "tail".  I also added an explicit `root@` but you don't need that.  It just simplified my testing.

Perhaps the ls is overflowing.  Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Global Crontab Inventory for Scripts
#
outputfile="/localpath/cronoutput.txt"
LPARLIST=LPAR.txt

cat $LPARLIST |
while read LPAR; 
do
ping -c 1 $LPAR > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
ssh -n root@$LPAR ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs |
while read user
do
    ssh -n "root@$LPAR" tail -n +29 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$user |
    while read line;
    do
    echo "$LPAR $user $line"
    done
done
fi
done
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Same errors, it seems like it's trying to execute the entire line as a command, an it never seems to enter the while loop with the echo commands.  I do Like Cat instead though.

Also I know the first 29 lines are junk because these are all images of aix built from the same nim/mksysb. So they are all identical. I want the commented out scripts because I'm also trying to get an inventory of what might be ready for retirement and was left by installation rot.